# Wordpress Admin - How to set #wpcontent to 100% height (to match adminmenuwrap)

Tags: wordpress, admin

I am seriously losing it today. Anyone know how I can set #wpcontent to be 100% height like adminmenuwrap is? Creating a plugin and want the background to be 100% height. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How is it behaving when you set it to 100%? Does it seem like anything happens when you set it to a pixel height? This would let us know if the css is working at all. Then we can look at the div it's in. also have you tried using !important; ?